# How to create a solution local nuget package in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a Nuget package I'd like to put into source control with my main solution under a folder

```
.../myproject/vendor/NugetLocal
```

and I might have

```
.../myproject/vendor/NugetLocal/Foo.7.0.196.nupkg
```

plus others within in

How do I update the package sources to point to nuget packages stored in this folder. The package explorer settings within VS2012 will not allow me to put in a relative path. I've tried my solution Nuget.Config as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>

    <packageSources>
        <add key="Local TO Solution" value="..\vendor\NugetLocal" />
    </packageSources>

    <disabledPackageSources />
    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)"  />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

but the package I have put in the directory does not seem to get found. I added the package to packages.config as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Foo" version="7.0.196" />
</packages>
```

just to test it out and package restore tells me that I need to download new packages but then it says it can't find package Foo

Comment: This changeset http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/591fe050b050#test/Core.Test/SettingsTests.cs suggests relative paths are ok. Maybe something else is going wrong.